# wordpress woocommerce image size - container is stretching the image

Tags: css, wordpress, image, size

First of all, i will apologise for my badly written english, never really went to school. So please be nice.

I have some problems with the website im building in wordpress.

I'm are using "the7" theme.

i have set the size, of the images in the product settings, and regenerated the images, with the plugin that there is recommended. And it it's working fine in the product page. But not in my custom "webshop" page. The container, where the images is stored, is simply to big. and i cant find any way to fix it.

The URL http://www.imobile.dk/webshop/

i would like the image to be 150x150. and it is, but it's is stretched. on my computer (617x617) original is 150x150.

dose anyone has any idea, how to fix this?

i think the theme it self, is overwriting the default settings.

i really need you're guys help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following: In your wp-admin go to "appearence" -> "Editor" and then put this in your style.css file:

```
.woo-buttons-on-img {
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: That did not help, am really lost here :-/

Comment: did you refresh the page? It seems to work now if I take a look at the page

Comment: Oh! I forgot to refresh local cache

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I owe you one!