# wordpress woocommerce image size - container margin and sizing

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Yesterday, I got some help, with my wordpress webshop show recent product page. the problem is, that, if I change the size, of the images in product viewing settings, it has no effect on the site. I think, that the theme itself, is overriding the tamplate from woocommerce.

my site here http://www.imobile.dk/webshop/

My first question [wordpress woocommerce image size - container is stretching the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272634/wordpress-woocommerce-image-size-container-is-stretching-the-image)

I would like my result to be something like this. on a smooth line. but I really, do not have any ideas of how.

[image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovQla.png)

i have been trying to add something like this

```
.wf-cell {
max-width:150px;}
```

but without any luck..

and if I get the images in the right size, they are not margin close, they will be in the same spot, just smaller. så there can only be 2 products pr line.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Soo I found a solution by my self.

I added the following code, to the costume CSS in the editor

```
.woocom-project {
position: relative;
max-width: 200px;
}
.wf-cell {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
max-width: 225px;
}
```

And now it's working like a charm.